# Javascript: simple click sound for iOS/Safari and the rest of the browsers

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I have a sound that I want to play on click. Everything is working well, except on Safari/iOS. On iPhone this sound is played only once (first time). To fix this I add `.load()` before `.play()`.
Now, when I click on desired areas, there is sound for iPhone too.

```
var sound_obj = document.createElement("audio");
sound_obj.src="../sounds/clic.mp3";
sound_obj.volume=0.10;
sound_obj.autoPlay=false;
sound_obj.loop = false;
sound_obj.preLoad=true;
sound_obj.type = 'audio/mpeg';

$(document).on("vclick", ".elementwithsound", function () {
    sound_obj.load(); //this makes iOS to play the sounds but makes other browsers like firefox to throw errors sometimes
    sound_obj.play();
});
```

But on console now I have `GET https://xxxxxxx.xx/sounds/clic.mp3` for each click. Also, from time to time I have this error for the `sound_obj.load();` line:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The fetching process for the media resource was aborted by the user agent at the user's request.
```

Is there a nice way to implement such click sound for iOS and Android without this mess?